# Laravel 8 Raw query not working in Application but working fine in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have an SQL query as follow in which i am using joins to fetch records from 3 tables

```
SELECT users.employeeID, users.name, (SELECT DISTINCT MONTHNAME(cdate) from calendar WHERE 
cdate >= "2021-12-01" AND cdate<="2021-12-22") as AtnMonth, 

(SELECT COUNT(cdate) from calendar where is_holiday=0 and cdate >= "2021-12-01" AND 
cdate<=LAST_DAY("2021-12-22") ) as WorkingDays, 

(select count(calendar.cdate) from calendar where calendar.cdate IN (SELECT attandances.date 
FROM attandances WHERE attandances.employeeID = users.employeeID AND status="Present") AND 
calendar.is_holiday=0 and calendar.cdate >= "2021-12-01" AND calendar.cdate<="2021-12-22" ) as 
present, 

(select count(calendar.cdate) from calendar where calendar.cdate IN ( SELECT attandances.date 
FROM attandances WHERE attandances.employeeID = users.employeeID AND status="Unpaid Halfday") 
AND calendar.is_holiday=0 and calendar.cdate >= "2021-12-01" AND calendar.cdate<="2021-12-22") 
as UnpaidHalfdays, 

(select count(c.cdate) from calendar c left join attandances a on c.cdate = 
a.date and a.employeeID=users.employeeID where a.status="Absent" OR a.date is null and c.cdate 
>= "2021-12-01" AND c.cdate<="2021-12-22" and c.is_holiday=0 ) as Absents from users;
```

it is working as expected and giving the following results
[image: SQL QUERY OUTPUT]

but when i try to execute same query in laravel as follow:

```
DB::select(DB::raw('SELECT users.employeeID, users.name, 
     (SELECT  MONTHNAME(cdate) from calendar WHERE cdate >= "?" AND cdate<="?") 
     as AtnMonth,
     (SELECT COUNT(cdate) from calendar where is_holiday=0 and cdate >= "?" AND 
cdate<=LAST_DAY("?")  ) as WorkingDays,
(select count(calendar.cdate) from calendar where calendar.cdate  IN (SELECT attandances.date 
FROM attandances WHERE attandances.employeeID = users.employeeID AND status="Present") AND  
calendar.is_holiday=0 and calendar.cdate >= "?" AND calendar.cdate<="?" ) as present,
    (select count(calendar.cdate) from calendar where calendar.cdate  IN ( SELECT 
attandances.date FROM attandances WHERE attandances.employeeID = users.employeeID AND 
status="Unpaid Halfday") 
    AND  calendar.is_holiday=0 and calendar.cdate >= "?" AND calendar.cdate<="?") 
    as UnpaidHalfdays, 
     
(select count(c.cdate) as absents from calendar c left join attandances a on c.cdate = 
a.date and a.employeeID=users.employeeID  where a.status="Absent" OR a.date is null 
and  c.cdate >= "?" AND c.cdate<="?"  and c.is_holiday=0 ) as Absents  from users ;', 
[$details_dateFrom, $details_dateTo,   $details_dateFrom,$details_dateTo,   
$details_dateFrom,$details_dateTo,   $details_dateFrom,$details_dateTo,   
$details_dateFrom,$details_dateTo]));
```

here `$details_dateFrom` and `$details_dateTo` are variables have date in mysql format (Y-m-d);

it is giving the following output:
[image: Laravel OUTPUT]

is there anything wrong with my query or in my laravel code?

Comment: Try removing the DB::raw call, it's not needed with DB::select

Comment: Also remove the quotes around the placeholders. That is changing it from a placeholder to a quoted literal question mark

Comment: thanks.@aynber  It worked. but can you please explain why DB::raw wasn't working ? I still can't figure it out as i am sending a raw query but it wasn't fetching expected results

Comment: The DB::raw might have been okay, though in my IDE, it's saying DB::raw does not take more than 1 argument, so it was probably ignoring the passed array . The quoted placeholders definitely was breaking it.